# JPA insert query spring boot

Tags: sql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have class `City` which is:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="city",schema="rezervisi")
public class City {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Getter
@Setter
private int id;
@Getter
@Setter
@NotBlank(message = "Name is mandatory")
private String name;
}
```

Now I want to override save method in which I send object city. How can I do it if i want to send whole object and not @Params separately. And also since ID is generated how I handle it through parameter here?

Code for repository class is:

```
public interface CityRepo extends JpaRepository<City,Integer> {

@Query(value="select id, name from city where id = :id ", nativeQuery = true)
Optional<City> findById(Integer id);

@Query(value="select id, name from city where name = :name ", nativeQuery = true)
City findByName(String name);

@Modifying
@Query(value = "insert into city (id,name) VALUES (:id,:name)", nativeQuery = true)
City save(City city ); // instead City save(@Param("id) int id .... 

void delete(City city);
}
```

Comment: Actually I didn't get what you want exactly  .. but please have a look at this question you may find something useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60682315/spring-data-jpa-native-query-insert-object

Answer (score 0):

1. You can try using `repository.save(city)` from your service if it is a `CrudRepository`.
2. If that is not what you need for some reason, you can try this out:

```
    @Modifying
    @Transactional
    @Query(value = "insert into city (id, name) VALUES (?, ?)", nativeQuery = true)
    City save(Long id, String name);
    
    default City save(City city) {
        return save(city.getId(), city.getName());
    }
```